# How to validate if output of a SQL predicate intersects with output of another SQL predicate before actually querying on the data?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, partiql

Is there any known algorithm or library which can help in determining if a SQL predicate is contained in another SQL predicate?

These predicate will come after this statement

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

For example, let's see this predicate

```
name = Smith
```

I want to check if that predicate is contained in the following predicate:

```
(company = Walmart OR hobby = baseball) AND (NOT (name != Smith))
```

I am trying to figure out if the output of second predicate has possibility of containing output of the first predicate or not. This information is required before querying on the actual data.

Constraints:

1. Nested predicates are not allowed.
2. Only these operators are allowed: AND OR NOT BETWEEN IN IS.

Comment: I haven't looked at this exact problem, but from past experience this is part of query optimizers and the code for sqlite is usually quite readable and well documented.

Comment: On another note, on dbs like postgres this would be optimized and won't be a real problem. Do you really need this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "chance"? SQL deals with actual data, not abstracts such as relational algebra. Are you writing some kind of parser, or do you Actually want to know if one set is a member of another set? (Not whether there's a chance, whether it's actually true or not.) And then, are you talking about sub-sets or intersections? And how do you want to present the result, as a true/false, or the whole of set a, provided it's a sub-set of set b?

Comment: @MatBailie I want to know in advance before querying on the actual data.  Output should be true or false. I am interested in knowing if the intersection is not null or alternatively if the negation of predicate is a subset.

Comment: @NuLo Yes, I need this.

Comment: So, you want to write a parser?  Read in two SQL statements and determine algebraically whether the two are mutually exclusive or not?  *(If this is for performance, databases already optimise for this.  If you query `WHERE a = 1 AND a = 2` or `WHERE a = 1 AND a <> 1`, the planner will understand that there are no rows to read...)*

Comment: Yes, I want to write parser to determine algebraically. This is a requirement at application level. I don't need this for performance.

Answer (score 1):

[Truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) can help with this.

You can express every term in your boolean expression as either true or false. Or equivalently, different possible inputs that result in each term being true or false.

Make a table of every combination of these.

| company | hobby | name | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Walmart | baseball | Smith | TRUE |
| Walmart | golf | Smith | TRUE |
| Costco | golf | Smith | `FALSE` |
| Costco | golf | Jones | FALSE |
| Walmart | baseball | Jones | FALSE |

There are other combinations, but I'm leaving them out.

Then make a truth table for the predicate you want to test: `name = Smith`

| company | hobby | name | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Walmart | baseball | Smith | TRUE |
| Walmart | golf | Smith | TRUE |
| Costco | golf | Smith | `TRUE` |
| Costco | golf | Jones | FALSE |
| Walmart | baseball | Jones | FALSE |

The second predicate is not a subset of the first, because in the first, there are at least one set of inputs for which the result FALSE even though `name = Smith` is true. I've highlighted the result that is different from the first predicate.

What's missing from my answer is a method to parse the boolean expression and identify the terms so you can make the truth table. This depends on what language you use, and so on. You can search past Stack Overflow answers for similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+sql+boolean+expression

As for recommending a library or software product that can do this for you, that's beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. The [guidelines for on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically say that this site is not intended for recommendations for software libraries or tools.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem but it has given me a good jump start. Thanks a lot.